# Is there a way to control the app and notification volumes at once on a phone like there is on a tablet?

Tags: volume-control

Whenever I want to change the volume for apps on my phone, I have to open up an app that makes sound. If I try to do it at other times, it only changes the notification volume with no option for others.

Like [this page](http://kiledjian.com/main/2013/2/15/app-and-notification-volume-control-on-android.html) says, this is an option for tablets, where you can just expand the volume controls when they pop up and then adjust either one. Is there a way to get this expanding functionality on a phone?

I guess that they made it like that to save screen space, but neither a button nor a slider bar comes anywhere close to filling up my screen, and I would appreciate being able to do this.

I have a rooted Nexus 4 with Android 4.4.2 and have the Xposed Framework installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change media volume when no media is being played?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9815/how-can-i-change-media-volume-when-no-media-is-being-played)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that CyanogenMod has something like this, but I didn't really want to install that just for easier volume controls. I found that there's an [Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/) module called [GravityBox](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.gm2.gravitybox) that includes this. It included a lot of other stuff that I didn't care about too, but thankfully someone extracted this specific feature and repackaged it as [ExpandableVolume](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.gm2.gravitybox.volumepanel). I installed that, and it works great now!!

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmADb.jpg)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkROp.png)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your Android version and device, but based on what you said it seems like you should be able to. You can try **Volume** in Settings, or you can download [Volume Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cb.volumePlus&hl=en) and control various different volume levels and settings.

Several attempts to get this are [posted here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-samsung-galaxy-nexus/140287-separate-ringtone-notification-volumes-possible-ics.html), but it doesn't seem like some devices have it.

Comment: Volume Control can control the volume, but it doesn't change how the physical volume rocker behaves.

Your second link just seems to be about [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37242/can-i-have-different-volumes-settings-for-notifications-and-ringtones-with-nexus).

Answer (score 0):

I like [Slider Widget - Volumes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.hinterhofapps.sliderwidget).

> A small Widget that gives control of the screen brightness and the sound volume directly from your home screen. You can easily manage those with the widget's slider or your hardware buttons. With a double click, you can also use the buttons to toggle. Slider Widget shows 6 Categories (e.g brightness or ring volume), which you can choose from 7 categories (more below). You can also change the order of the categories displayed in Slider Widget.